# What is the smallest positive integer value satisfies N if 2016N is a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic

I came across this question which says:

[image]

I tried the question like this:
If 2016N is a perfect square number then 2016N=$2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7*N$.So for 2016N to be a perfect square the square root of it also must be a whole number, and the smallest at the same time. So 2016N must equal$2^2\cdot3^2\cdot7^2*N$.Then I thought that then$$2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot7^2 =2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7*N $$
$$ \therefore N=\frac{7}{8}$$

But my problem starts here.There is no answer in the question that is similar to $N=\frac{7}{8}$ ,if you read the question again. So is my method wrong, or do you know of a better way of answering this question? Please feel free to answer the question.

Comment: $7/8$ is not an integer.

Comment: Please explain how you got from the equation $$2016 = 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7
$$ to the equation 
$$2016 \, N = 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7
$$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the N

Comment: You can't make the $2^5$ get smaller so you can't have $2^5\times 3^2 \times 7\times N = 2^2\times 3^2\times 7^2$.  But you can have $2^5\times 3^2\times 7 \times N = 2^6\times 3^2\times 7^2$.  And to do that you have $N = 2\times 7 = 14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "So for 2016N to be a perfect square the square root of it also must be a whole number, and the smallest at the same time. "

Okay.... let turn those words into math!

We need

$2^5\times 3^2 \times 7 N = M^2$ so

$\sqrt{2^5\times 3^2 \times 7\times N} = M \in \mathbb Z$.

$\sqrt{2^5\times 3^2\times 7\times N}=\sqrt{2^4\times 2 \times 3^2 \times 7\times N} = 2^2\times 3\times \sqrt{2\times 7N}= M$.

So we need $\sqrt{2\times 7\times N}$ to be an integer and the smallest possible integer.

That means $2\times 7 \times N$ must be a perfect square and $14$ must be a factor of this perfect square and $2\times 7\times N$ must be the smallest such perfect square divisible by $14$ so.... well, that just means that $2\times 7\times N$ must *be* $14^2$ and $N$ must be equal to $14$!

That's all.

And we can *easily* see it works.  $(2^5\times 3^2\times 7)\times 14 = 2^6\times 3^2 \times 7^2 = (2^3 \times 3\times 7)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

An integer is a perfect square if and only if each prime factor appears an even number of times, so the smallest such $N$ satisfies
$$2016N = 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7 \times N = 2^6 \times 3^2 \times 7^2.$$
Now solve for $N$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** An integer with prime factorization $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is a square iff all of the $e_1,\dots,e_k$ are even. Thus, you want to find the minimal $N=2^{e_1}3^{e_2}\cdots$ such that $2016N=2^{5+e_1}3^{2+e_2}5^{e_3}7^{1+e_4}\cdots$ is a square, which happens when each of $5+e_1,2+e_2,e_3,1+e_4,\dots$ are even. (Note also that you need all the $e_i$'s to be nonnegative.)